# Find the angle between two lines given their angles

Tags: geometry

I'd like to find the angle between two lines given the angle of the lines from their positive x axis. The lines form a path but I am looking for the angle between the two lines. The angles of the two lines A and B can be in the range 0 deg to 359 deg. I am looking for C - the angle between the two lines. Refer to the image for a better illustration:

[image: Lines with angles]

Comment: $\angle C=\angle A-\angle B + 180^\circ$

Comment: Hint: Consider the sum of $B$ and $C$, and the complement of $A$.

Comment: I am looking to form a triangle and so C must be the side that is < 180°. How do I handle this when A and B are approaching 360°?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image, due to the angle of the part below the dotted line being $A$ and the part above's angle being the supplement of $B$, you have

$$C = A + (180^{o} - B) = 180^{o} + A - B \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

This is basically assuming that $0 \le A,B \le 180^{o}$. However, as your question text says $A$ and $B$ can be up to $359^{o}$, I'm not sure how you define your $C$ where either $A$ or $B$ is more than $180^{o}$. Based on the OP's later question comment to require $C \lt 180^{o}$, one way to do that is to have \eqref{eq1} be modulo $180^{o}$, i.e., add or subtract $180^{o}$, as needed, until $0 \le C \lt 180^{o}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend the first line a bit, you see that the angle, going counterclockwise from the first line until you reach the second line, is given by $B-A$. If you want the supplement of that angle, as seems to be the case from your diagram, you'll want $180 - (B-A) = 180 + A - B.$

Note that the answer depends very much on your conventions for how you're labeling the lines and angles. I'm assuming here that your diagram is accurate.